# Exchange service doesn't work in Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, outlook, azure-functions, exchange-server

Here is my code for initializing the Exchange service.

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate (
            object s,
            X509Certificate certificate,
            X509Chain chain,
            SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors
        ) {
            return true;
        };
        //Instantiate a new ExchangeService object
        var exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);

        //Set the exchange WebService URL
        exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        //Set the credentials of the service to the credentials
        //that are associated with the impersonating account.
        exchangeService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userId, password);
```

It works perfectly on my local system and I am able to create an appointment using it.
But, after moving the above code into an Azure function, it returns the following error while initializing Exchange service.

Error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: The path is empty.
>       Parameter name: path
>       at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
>       at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
>       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsUtilities.<.cctor>b__9()
>       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LazyMember`1.get_Member()
>       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsUtilities.get_BuildVersion()
>       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase..cctor()
>       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>        at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase..ctor(TimeZoneInfo
>   timeZone)
>        at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService..ctor()
>       at Submission#0.d__1.MoveNext() in D:\home\site\wwwroot\
>       2020-01-27T10:55:35.631 [Information] Exception =============== : The type initializer for 
>       'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase' threw an exception.

Is there anything else required for an Azure function?

Comment: Based on your question I have a lot of additional questions, like: Are you sure of the Exchange version? Did you specify the correct username and password? And, maybe most importantly: why not use [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph)?

Comment: Locally it worked using version "Exchange2013_SP1" and the user name and the password. So I am sure about that. Using  Microsoft Graph  and Azure AD we need to login to our account. That way not suitable for my project and concept. Hope you can help with this Thank you